# Iterating through an array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hey everyone,
   I am trying to iterate though an array of strings when I click a button in my iPhone app. In the viewDidLoad method this code works great, however, I am using a Tab Bar to switch between views, and I want the view to refresh itself when i switch to it from another view. This is the code it is breaking around, very similar to code I am using in another button that works perfectly

```
        NSEnumerator *e = [deckList objectEnumerator];
        id obj;
```

It crashes whenever it gets to "id obj"
Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: `id obj` line should virtually never crash as it's nothing but a memory allocation. Could you give us more of the code?

Comment: can u provide an error message?

Comment: What the hell does this have to do with Xcode? (As such, I've retagged your question).

Comment: @Mo `id obj` is certainly not a memory allocation.

Comment: U see the tag "xcode" a lot on these kinds of questions. I believe, people mix up the terms "xcode" and "cocoa(-touch)"

Comment: @vikingosegundo Indeed. So annoying; thanks for retagging! :)

Comment: @Jonathan Sterling: I do it a dozen time every day

Comment: The error message that comes from the orignal code is "Program recieved signal: SIGABRT"

Comment: @Jonathan Sterling: id obj; is absolutely a memory allocation; it's little else.  It may not allocate heap memory, but that pointer value has to live somewhere.  Don't disrespect the stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (NSString* string in arrayOfStrings ){
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

[The Objective-C Programming Language — Fast Enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18-SW1)

Comment: Bah, beaten because I tried to solve his crashing problem too. *shakes fist*

Comment: With the original code given it says "Program received signal: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: Search SO for "NSZombieEnabled", I am quite sure, it will help you

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the "NSZombieEnabled" that lead me right to it!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that as @vikingosegundo pointed me to in an NSZombieEngabled thread, I had not initialized the ids to nil. The simple fix of:

```
 id obj = nil;
```

solved all my problems!